# Excel Formatting Issue Without Being Administrator

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, formatting

Having a real weird issue. A few excel files sent to my office open fine as Administrator. However, as a standard account it opens with all of the cells shrunk and the formatting completely messed up. You also can't see what's in the cells. Some of the other tabs work fine though which is really strange.

Comment: This looks like it will soon be migrated to Super User where you will likely get a better answer. Maybe you could update your question with what you have tried to diagnose the problem so far. Have you tried different computers? Are the versions of Excel the same? You know, help us help you and all that.

Comment: Is the Excel file from a 2007 source?  Does it contain macros?

Comment: The file is a 2003 type of file (xls). However, it's not a macro enabled workbook file. If I turn the account to a local admin, the file opens with the proper formatting. This issue only appears to be happening on our Terminal Server. I'm going to test tomorrow and see if copy/pasting into a new workbook fixes the issue and then I'll update again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being that the fonts in these files were different. For whatever reason the fonts were located in the Administrators user profile. In the Windows fonts folder there were shortcuts pointing to this file in the profile. I couldn't delete the shortcuts and add the real fonts so I just gave read access to the fonts folder in the administrator profile and it all started working.